# How do I send file(s) via ajax without using html form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, upload

I am experiencing difficulties with uploading files via ajax without sing html form.
My case is like this:

1. I have a textarea
2. I would like to zip the content of that textarea and upload it to the server via AJAX (right now I am using [JSZip](http://stuartk.com/jszip/))
3. For testing purpose, I try to create a dummy zip file to send like this (not getting textarea content):

   ```
   var zip = new JSZip();
   zip.file("hello1.txt", "Hello First World\n");<br/>
   zip.file("hello2.txt", "Hello Second World\n");<br/>
   var content = zip.generate();
   ```
4. Then I use Jquery ajax method to send, like this:

   ```
   $.post("the_url",
       {
           GradeRequest : {
               submitter_id : "foobar",
               evaluationset_id : 9,
               mode : 1,
               source_file : "a.cpp",
               file: content
           }
       }
   );
   ```

But the file is not received on the server.
I have read question in [How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery), but all solutions are using html form. Is there any solution which does not involve any html form ?

Thanks in advance.

In the server side, I'm using Yii PHP Framework:

```
$model = $this->model;
    if ($model !== null && isset($_POST['GradeRequest'])) {
        $model->setAttributes($_POST['GradeRequest']);

        if ($model->validate()) {
            if (isset($_FILES['GradeRequest']['tmp_name']['file']) && $_FILES['GradeRequest']['tmp_name']['file'] !== "") {
                $model->file = file_get_contents($_FILES['GradeRequest']['tmp_name']['file']);
                $model->source_file = $_FILES['GradeRequest']['name']['file'];
            }

            $this->setReply(true, "Ok");
            $model->client_id = $this->clientId;
            $model->request_id = $this->requestRecord->id;
            $model->save();
        } else {
            $this->setReply(false, $model->getErrors());
        }
    }
```

As a proof of concept, I have created a form version like this and it works (the file got uploaded to the server):

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="[the_url]>
EvaluationSet id: <input type="text" name="GradeRequest[evaluationset_id]" /><br />
<input type="hidden" name="GradeRequest[mode]" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" name="GradeRequest[submitter_id]" value="Someone" />

Source file : <input type="text" name="GradeRequest[source_file]" /><br />
File : <input type="file" name="GradeRequest[file]" /><br />

<input type="submit" />
```

Comment: Please post the code you're running on the server. You should be able to access the file from the POST array.

Comment: @JamWaffles: code added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There the `FormData` object that can help you (it's part of the so called `xmlHttpRequest` version 2): this is a [compatibility chart](http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2), with some linked references and examples.

With that, you can add key/value pairs to the POST form, including `File` objects, and send it all via the common `send` method of `xmlHttpRequest`.

`File` objects can be easily retrieved using a `<input type="file">` element, or even using drag & drop from your desktop.

If you want to upload some file *content* as a file, you'll have to create a `Blob`. This feature is still experimental but supported by Chrome and Firefox (at least... and Safari I guess?):

```
var builder = new BlobBuilder();
builder.append(content);
var blob = builder.getBlob("application/zip");
```

Keep in mind that at this moment you'll have to use `MozBlobBuilder` in Firefox and `WebKitBlobBuilder` in Chrome instead.

In some tutorials I've seen that the string is actually converted into a `Uint8Array` first. Maybe that's based on a older reference, because the `append` method of `BlobBuilder` should accept plain strings too. Never tried it though.

If your content is a Base64 encoded string, you'll have to convert it using `atob` (should be supported by every browser that also supports `Blob` and `FormData`).

**Edit**: `BlobBuilder` is now deprecated due to the new draft of the Blob constructor. So everything you'll have to do to get the `Blob` is:

```
var blob = new Blob([content], "application/zip");
```

The rest is quite simple:

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append("file", blob);
```

The problem here is that the file name on the server side is unpredictable and depends on the user agent. I've seen some uses of `append` with a third parameter specifying the file name, but I guess it's a good idea to send the actual file name to a separate key/value pair in the `FormData` object.

Comment: for the [compatibility chart](http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2), I don't really understand about it. Could you please explain more ?

Yes, I am aware with the easy usage of <input type="file">, but the problem is: I wanted to send file from the text entered by the user, not from existing file in computers.

Comment: You'll still need `FormData`, but you can begin explaining how JSZip works. Does it create a file? And where? Locally? On a server?

Comment: In the [JSZip](http://stuartk.com/jszip/) example, they use:
`var content = zip.generate();
location.href="data:application/zip;base64,"+content;`

I think the 'created' file is in the content variable. There is no real file created in the client computer.

Comment: So all you have is a base64 string. This is a little bit complex, since if you *have* to send a file, and not a string, you'll have to create one first. The only browser that allows you to do that at the moment, supporting a decently complete FileAPI library, is Google Chrome.

Comment: oouucchh....so it's currently not possible to fake the file-creation and send it via XHR.

Do you think I should send the textarea content as a plain string ? Would that be a good workaround ?

Comment: I have tried the form data [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects), I sent a text file and it successfully uploaded to the server. Thanks a lot for the insight !!

But then, I tried again to send the base64 string from JSZip, it is uploaded, but the file is corrupted in the server. Is this what you mean on the previous comment ? Or do you have any other workaround for this ?

Comment: To be honest, I've forgot about the `Blob` way. So you can create a BlobBuilder object, append your data (after converting it from base64 using `atob`) and retrieving the `Blob` object using `builder.getBlob("application/zip")`. Then append the `Blob` to the `FormData` object. You're done. I'll edit the answer to respond to your actual demand.

Answer (score 1):

I finally get it through !! Many thanks for [MaxArt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/714240/maxart).

Basically, it is what [MaxArt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/714240/maxart) has said with Uint8Array conversion. I got the conversion reference from Eric Bidelman [here](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/chromium-html5/WOxmqfDAaqo).

Here's how I've done it:

```
var zip = new JSZip();
zip.file("hello1.txt", "Hello First World\n");
zip.file("hello2.txt", "Hello Second World\n");
var content = zip.generate(); //Generate dummy zip file (adjust to your need)

var oBlob = new (window.BlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder || window.MozBlobBuilder)(); //Instantiate blob builder

var raw = atob(content);    //decode the base64 string
var rawLength = raw.length;
var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(rawLength);
for (var i = 0; i < rawLength; ++i) { //convert to uInt8Array
    uInt8Array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
}

oBlob.append(uInt8Array.buffer); //append it to blobbuilder
oMyForm.append("GradeRequest[file]", oBlob.getBlob("application/zip")); //because you create a zip file, so get the zip type

//send it
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("POST", "{{the_url}}");
oReq.send(oMyForm);
```